# Create multiple files at once with fish shell

Tags: bash, fish, brace-expansion

I'm trying to create a few files at once using this syntax `touch foo{0..9}`, my desired output are ten files numbered from 0 to 9, but this only works when I'm using bash, if I switch to [fish](https://fishshell.com) it creates a single file like this "foo1..9".

OS is Debian 9 4.9.0-8-amd64 and fish version is 2.7.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest with fish shell:

```
touch foo(seq 0 9)
```